# What is the point of a django virtualenv, if when deploying with apache, wsgi.py is executed on the server NOT in the virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, apache2

I have my apache config set up to point to my virtualenv, but when i load the page and look at the error log it gives the following error:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

apache2 000-default.conf file:

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess project python-home=/home/django/config/env python-path=/usr/local/bfx/Databases/project
    WSGIProcessGroup project
    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/bfx/Databases/project/project/wsgi.py
```

Basically, it will work if I install django, and all my django packages on my server, but what is the point of the virtual env?

Thanks

Comment: Er, what? You install your packages inside the virtualenv on the server. That is what requirements.txt or Pipenv is for.

Comment: yes, but I get an error saying they are not installed

Comment: But did you install them? Did you run `pip install -r requirements.txt` on the server?

Comment: yes I have installed all of my requirements on my virtualenv on the server (which is python-home in WSGIDaemonProcess) - but I get errors - I.e if i uninstall django on my server (not venv): File "/usr/local/bfx/Databases/HTSv2/HTS/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Comment: but on my virtualenv, I can go into python and import this no problem - so something is wrong with apache2, but i dont know what, as i have defined the venv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualenv allows to create isolated environments. So you could create and run multiple projects with different versions of the same library without conflicts, for example.

You have to install all libraries in the server too. Virtualenv do not create a bundle nor deploy it.